# Throw HTTPResponseException direct to client

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have an api implemented under an ApiController in an MVC (Asp.net 4.5.2). In that api, I want to throw a HttpResponseException with a HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) and specify a ReasonPhrase. How can this be sent directly to the client rather than having asp/mvc try to redirect them to a login page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.Net Form Authentication module converts 401 to 302

If you using UseCookieAuthentication, then suppress this by changing OnApplyRedirect

File Startup.Auth.cs  **-->**    ConfigureAuth method **-->**   inside app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider { **-->**   Add OnApplyRedirect

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnApplyRedirect = context =>
                {
                    if (!context.Request.Uri.LocalPath.StartsWith(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/api")))
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I do not think I fully understand your instructions. I have added the snippet to Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) just below  ConfigureAuth(app);, but I am still getting redirected to login.

Comment: Not below startup.configuration. Please go to file startup.auth.cs. Search for line app.UseCookieAuthentication. Inside UseCookieAuthentication, when you set provider, copy paste this code (to override OnApplyRedirect)

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. API can now returned detailed explanations with auth or api errors, and authentication for the rest of the app is unchanged.

Comment: Also note, this code will suppress 302 for virtual path /api. You may have to change that as per you requirement. In case your api's don't have /api in virtual path, then use logic to identify your api.

Answer (score 1):

```
var message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
message.ReasonPhrase = "Hello";
throw new HttpResponseException(message);
```

But redirect depends on Web.config settings. I think you have authentication section in web.config somethink like this:

```
  <system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="/Login/Index"></forms>
  </authentication>
  </system.web>
```

If you delete this section, redirection won't happen. But in this case you should implement authentication on your own.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am doing. But instead of the client receiving the error message, they get bounced to a login page. I want the client calling the api to get the error.

Comment: Where does redirect happend on server-side or on client-side?

Comment: As best I understand it, mvc sees the Unauthorized status code and routes the request to the login page. I just want it to return an error.